# How to remove Incompatible pointer to integer conversion in an animation block warning

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewanimation

I'm getting a "Incompatible pointer to integer conversion" in an animation block and am unsure how to get rid of it.

here's the code where it appears and a screenshot below:

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                              delay:0.0f
                            options:nil
                         animations:^{
                             [menuView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 64.0f, 320.0f, 54.0f)];
                             menuView.alpha = 1.0;
                         }
                         completion:nil];
```

[image]

thanks for any help

Comment: the `options:` must be a numeric value, therefore you have to use the `0` instead of the `nil`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `options` parameter is not an object or pointer type, so of course you'll get this. It's an enumeration type, which is an alias of an appropriate integral type (i.e. `int`.) To pass no options, pass `0` or `kNilOptions`.

Answer (score 3):

You should read the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW109). Normally they will tell you what something will accept.

It looks like in this case you have to use a [Constant](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewAnimationOptions).

For example:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                              delay:0.0f
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                         animations:^{
                             [menuView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 64.0f, 320.0f, 54.0f)];
                             menuView.alpha = 1.0;
                         }
                         completion:NULL;
```